# GoBack() with Android Hardware Back Button and componentDidMount()

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

First, sorry for my english.

I'm trying to handle the hardware android back button using React Navigation and BackHandler. But, I can't really use goBack() react-navigation function.

So, I got a class androidBackButton.js that is :

```
import {BackHandler, Alert} from 'react-native';

const handleAndroidBackButton = callback => {
BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
callback();
return true;
});
};

const removeAndroidBackButtonHandler = () => {
BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {});
}

const exitAlert = () => {
Alert.alert(
"Quitter l'application",
"Êtes vous sûr de vouloir quitter l'application ?",
[
{text: 'Non', style: 'cancel'},
{text: 'Oui', onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp()},
]
);
};

export {handleAndroidBackButton, removeAndroidBackButtonHandler, exitAlert};
```

To use it, I use componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount in a screen like that :

```
componentDidMount() {
handleAndroidBackButton(this.props.navigation.goBack());
}

componentWillUnmount() {
removeAndroidBackButtonHandler();
}
```

But.. Like you certainly know, I can't call a props in componentDidMount because I'll got a warning that is 'Can't perform a React State update on an unmounted component.'. Even if the action is only call when I push the android hardware back button, it try to define it when I load the component. So, this is not working.

By the way, I try to define it like that :

`componentDidMount() { handleAndroidBackButton(() => {this.props.navigation.goBack()}); }`

By this way, no warning is displaying. But when I click the hardware button, nothing is happening..

So yes, somebody has an idea of what is happening ? Is there a way to achieve this without creating any errors ?

Thanks so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code like in the example of RN:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.backHandler.remove()
  }

 handleBackPress = () => {
    this.props.navigation.goBack(); // React Navigation goBack
    return true;
  }
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler.html

Comment: Don't forget to bind handleBackPress() in the constructor.

Comment: is not necessary because we are using an arrow function in handleBackPress

Comment: oops, my bad. I didn't notice it (Y)

Comment: I'm doing like you said but it seems that when i press on the back button, it is doing goBack() but it doesn't return to previous screen. It is going to the default screen.

Comment: I'm using a DrawerNavigator to have a sort of SideBar, maybe the goBack function is only accepting StackNavigator ?

Answer (score 0):

To continue my last comment ;

Here is my Navigator :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import HomeScreen from "./HomeScreen.js";
import SideBar from "../SideBar/SideBar.js";
import LoginScreen from "../LoginScreen/LoginScreen.js";
import KoustSettings from "../Settings/Settings.js";
import OrderScreen from "../OrderScreen/OrderScreen.js";
import CreateOrder from "../OrderScreen/CreateOrderScreen.js";
import CompleteOrder from "../OrderScreen/CompleteOrderScreen.js";

import FileScreen from "../FileScreen/FileScreen.js";
import InventoryScreen from "../InventoryScreen/InventoryScreen.js";
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

const RootDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
    Accueil: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Commandes: { screen: OrderScreen },
    Inventaires: { screen: InventoryScreen },
    Recettes: { screen: FileScreen },
    Settings: {screen: KoustSettings},
    CreateOrder: {screen: CreateOrder},
    CompleteOrder: {screen: CompleteOrder}
  },
  {
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />,
    unmountInactiveRoutes: true
  }
);
export default createAppContainer(RootDrawer);
```

Maybe only stackNavigator is providing a good use of goBack() ?

Comment: Yes. DrawerNavigator doesn't have that functionality to go back with one step. You have to make DrawerNavigator and after that make nested StackNavigator in it, so you will be on stack navigator's page and you will be able to use mentioned functionality without any kind of problem.

Comment: Yes it was the solution. Thanks.